# C# DateTime Parsing - inconsistent format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have an example date / time string that I need to convert to datetimeoffset.

There is one huge inconsistency - if the day of the month < 10 then there is a double space between Month and Day, otherwise just a single space.

For example: `'Tue Dec  4 22:39:38 UTC 2018'` and `'Tue Dec 14 22:39:38 UTC 2018'`

I currently parse it using `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateTime, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss UTC yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)` which fails for dates where the day is < 10 with the error:

```
FormatException: String 'Tue Dec  4 22:52:42 UTC 2018' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I know I can search and replace double space character with a single space, but is there a more elegant way to achieve this using the format string?

Comment: `I know I can search and replace double space character with a single space, but is there a more elegant way to achieve this using the format string?` That is what I would suggest. It is simple and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was just wondering if there is some kind of wildcard in string formatting or potentially a more flexible date parsing library in .NET ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite` flag?

Comment: `DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite`

Comment: Awesome, `DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite` did the trick! Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the `DateTimeStyles.Allow*` flags are for: They instruct the parser to ignore whitespaces in the date string.

In your case the string starts with the abbreviated weekday name, so the flag minimally sufficient to ignore the additional space in case of a one-digit day number is

```
DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite
```

This and related flags are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 5):

This question seemed to have a few comments (including my own erroneous one about using `AllowLeadingWhite` (I had meant `AllowInnerWhite`).

However, just using `AllowInnerWhite` with the existing format string still produces an error:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("Tue Dec  4 22:39:38 UTC 2018", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss UTC yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite));
```

Produces:

> FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

However, looking at this from a different angle, why not change the date format itself to permit single-digit dates.  Use `"ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTC yyyy"` (with a single 'd' for the actual date instead of 'dd'):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("Tue Dec  4 22:39:38 UTC 2018", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTC yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite));
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("Tue Dec 11 22:39:38 UTC 2018", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTC yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite));
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("Fri Dec 14 22:39:38 UTC 2018", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTC yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite));
```

Note that your example data of `'Tue Dec 14 22:39:38 UTC 2018'` will fail because Dec 14th 2018 is a Friday, not a Tuesday.